# Calculate $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{5^{n}+2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Calculate $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{5^{n}+2}$$

**My approach:** I know by the ratio test that the series converges.

---

However, how can I calculate the sum?

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? These sorts of sums tend not to have clean closed forms.

Comment: How do you conclude that you do not generally have a clean closed form? I saw the problem on an internet page as a serial hard problem.

Comment: _Most_ things don't have a clean closed form; there's no reason to expect that this does. I believe some similar constants have been proved transcendental, though I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: This has a closed form (in terms of q-digamma function). See this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+of+1%2F%285%5E%28n%29%2B2%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without special functions, we can make *approximations*. Let us write the infinite summation as
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac 1{5^n+2}+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac 1{5^n}\frac1{1+2\times 5^{-n}}$$ and write
$$\frac1{1+2\times 5^{-n}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \,2^k \times 5^{-nk}$$ Summing from $k=0$ to $k=6$ for example
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 1 & \color{red}{0.18976287}954938663595977935271628162746328531817419 \\
 2 & \color{red}{0.18976287877266}367299681638975331866450032235521123 \\
 3 & \color{red}{0.1897628787726615593}3180851573757063300425936308525 \\
 4 & \color{red}{0.1897628787726615593263284}9366930907000585425941698 \\
 5 & \color{red}{0.1897628787726615593263284796045}6167280726135887333 \\
 6 & \color{red}{0.189762878772661559326328479604525648}62133819307056 \\
 7 & \color{red}{0.189762878772661559326328479604525648529106}83382480 \\
 8 & \color{red}{0.189762878772661559326328479604525648529106597707}69 \\
 9 & \color{red}{0.18976287877266155932632847960452564852910659770708} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This's a interesting answer!

Comment: @Ramanujan. Thank you !